# How to use jquery autocomplete functionality in struts2 without using struts autocompleter tag

Tags: jsp, struts2, jquery-autocomplete

I am using jquery autocomplete functionality in struts2 without using struts autocompleter tag but its not work?

```
<html
 <head
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function({
    alert("Autocomplete");
    $("#cxttag").autocomplete("autocomplete.jsp"); 
 </script>
 </head>
  <body>
    <label>Enter Tag:</label>
    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Add a tag"  id="cxttag" name="bk.tag"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Integrating *jQuery-ui autocomplete* is not tough.  In your case the problem is with your code:

```
<html   //----- missed >
 <head   //----- missed >
  <script>
```

1) Missed to close `html` and `head` tags.
2) Missed to add both *`jQuery`* and [**jQuery-ui script**](https://jqueryui.com/) and *`jQuery-ui.css`* files.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />  
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Above are [*CDN hosted by Google*](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide).